# Add background color to gtk_overlay

Tags: c, gtk

I am using `gtk_overlay_new ()` to create an overlay in gtk, is there any way i can add some background color to it? so far i have not been successful in finding anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `void gtk_widget_override_background_color();`
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-override-background-color

Answer (score 0):

In GTK4 gtk_widget_override_background_color is no longer available. The same can be achieved with CSS using a style context.

```
GtkStyleContext *context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(someGtkWidget);
GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider, ".someClass { background: rgba(255,0,0,1)}", -1); //red
gtk_style_context_add_provider (context, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
gtk_style_context_add_class (context, "someClass");
```